# How do I conditionally add a class to my page title within page-title.html.twig?

Tags: 8, theming, nodes

I have a boolean field within my Page content type called *Hide Title*.

I need to conditionally add a class to h1's to visually hide them if this field is checked.

I have the following within *page-title.html.twig*

```
{% set hide_title = content.field_hide_title.0 %}

{% if 'On' in hide_title %}
    <h1 {{ title_attributes.addClass('visually-hidden') }}>{{ title }}</h1>
{% else %}
  <h1{{ title_attributes }}>{{ title }}</h1>
{% endif %}
```

This is is not adding the class while the boolean is set on or off.

Comment: Add `{{ hide_title }}` right after you set it, as a cheap way of finding out what the value you're getting is.

Comment: @beltouche Good idea – it's not returning anything, hmm. Tried changing to ***node**.field_hide_title.0* but still nothing.

Comment: I recommend turning on twig debugging and using dev to dig into the field so you can find what you're looking for. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `page-title.html.twig` you don't have access to `content` variable.
according to [`page-title.html.twig`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21page-title.html.twig/8.2.x) comment section:

Available variables are:

- title_attributes
- title_prefix
- title
- title_suffix

So you should implement [`hook_preprocess_HOOK`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x) to passe `hide_title` to your twig like the following:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYMODULE_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $variables['hide_title'] = $node->field_hide_title->value;
  }
}
```

Now you can do the following in your twig:

```
{% if hide_title == "1" %}
    <h1 {{ title_attributes.addClass('visually-hidden') }}>{{ title }}</h1>
  {% else %}
    <h1{{ title_attributes }}>{{ title }}</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Now that makes sense, thanks so much!

Comment: You are welcome, glad that helped!